# What's the best depth map generation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, methods, dictionary, depth

I'm into a 2D-to-3D application project and I'm looking for a method to produce the depth map of a single input image, without other external informations. I know that's a sort of "artificial intelligence" mattern but maybe an efficient algorythm exists.

At the moment I've found this one: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.7959&rep=rep1&type=pdf but I'm wondering if there is a better method, before start implementing. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Check http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/eval/ for the latest papers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written quite a few automatic depth map generators. I don't think there's one that's better than all others in all cases. It all depends on the stereo pair you're starting with. I personally think a depth map generator based on local method (window or block based) with an edge preserving smoother is probably the best all-around depth map generator.

In any case, on this page:

[depth map generation software](http://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/p/software.html)

you can find depth map generator software based on optical flow, weight-based windows, graph cuts, and many other things that relate to depth map generation and lenticular creation. The best part is that it's all free.

For 2d to 3d conversion (which is more what you are asking), there's a piece of software called DMAG4 that uses a scarsely populated depth map (typically, done in Gimp with the paint brush) to indicate the main depths and then fills the unfilled areas using interpolation while maintaining the edges of the objects (edge-preserving).

DMAG4 can be found here (it's free to use):

[2d to 3d conversion software DMAG4](http://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/2014/02/depth-map-automatic-generator-4-dmag4.html)

Another way to 2d to 3d conversion is to use a sculpting program like Gimpel3d or Blender, both free. Clearly, this goes beyond depth map since you're essentially creating a 3d scene in which you can then move around (using the camera movement in Blender). This is often referred to as "camera mapping".

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have recently come upon this:

http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/code.html

which comes together with code, although the license might be too restrictive
("Noncommercial — You may not use this work for commercial purposes").

the gallery is impressive

http://make3d.stanford.edu/images/showall

Comment: clicking on the "research" link  (http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/research.html) you are sent to a page with links to related papers (I did not try to understand them myself).

Comment: Most of the demos have a flat 'floor' that occupies a lower part of the image and a ‘wall’ for the upper half. It seems that this works as their prior and all they can recover. It doesn’t impress me. Nowadays people solve a problem using a single camera but still have a few shots with it and recover essential matrix to restore 3D up to scaling. This is a right way to go, while the question about 3D from a single 2D image is not very productive.